# How to get image URL of user from Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I want to use my content script and/or background script to grab an image *of* the user, as in take a picture of them and obtain the `data:` URI.

I have tried some code but it just shows me this image:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAEYklEQVR4Xu3UAQkAAAwCwdm/9HI83BLIOdw5AgQIRAQWySkmAQIEzmB5AgIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlACBB1YxAJfjJb2jAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Not sure why, but it's some sort of dim white.

Here is my code:

```js
// background.js

const player = document.createElement('video');
document.body.appendChild(player);
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var output=""; // This is going to be the output data URI

const constraints = {
  video: true,
};

setInterval(() => {
  // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
  context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  output=canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // Doesn't work

},5000);

// Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    player.srcObject = stream;
  }).catch((e)=>alert(e));
```

When I uninstall and reinstall my extension, I start seeing an invalid URL...

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAEaElEQVR4Xu3UgQkAMAwCQbv/0C10i4fLBHIGz7Y7R4AAgYDAMViBlkQkQOALGCyPQIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiBgsPwAAQIZAYOVqUpQAgQMlh8gQCAjYLAyVQlKgIDB8gMECGQEDFamKkEJEDBYfoAAgYyAwcpUJSgBAgbLDxAgkBEwWJmqBCVAwGD5AQIEMgIGK1OVoAQIGCw/QIBARsBgZaoSlAABg UHCBDICBisTFWCEiDwAMDYlgE33 xyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you are starting your interval before you are granted permission for the user camera. Also, your `player` does not have `autoplay=true`, so even if you get it correctly, your frame would never be updated.

I believe to fix you problem you should only start the `setInterval` after your stream has been initialized, try this:

`background.js`

```js
const player = document.createElement('video');
player.autoplay = true; // important

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then((stream) => {
        player.srcObject = stream;

        // makes sure to begin interval only after stream is set
        setInterval(() => {
          const userImg = document.getElementById('user-img');
          const imgUrl = captureImageUrl();
          console.log(imgUrl);
        }, 2000);
    }).catch((e)=>alert(e));

function captureImageUrl() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Also, to simulate your program, I created a simple web page with a script that captures an image of the user's webcam every 2 seconds and then places it into an image element.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/lnogueir/video-frame-capture-sample). Feel free to open an issue if you have questions.

Comment: One question - is `index.html` an extension page or a normal web page?

Comment: It is a normal web page

Comment: Hmmm... (1) `background.js` is an extension file so it can not be included into the web page.  (2) `startCapturing` is not defined because it seems that `background.js` can not add functions into the web page.

Comment: Good to know. I am not familiar with how scripts work within extensions but would adding an event listener for the button work (instead of calling it from the HTML)? Are you allowed to do that within the extension script?

Comment: Actually, seeing [this gist](https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399), I think I can inject a script to run your code on the web page from the background script.  Will test when I have time.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I have updated my answer to use an event listener instead of calling the function from the HTML. I am hoping that way you don't need to inject the script, so it's a bit less cumbersome.

Comment: Have you found a way to inject files?  The gist is not working for me, and using event listeners does not help.  I do want to give out the bounty, but no other answers are appearing and I can't inject the file.

Comment: How were you running your original script? If the event listener is also a problem, then we can get rid of buttons. I will update my answer one more time to make it look exactly how you had it before but assuring that the setInterval only starts after you've received the stream.

Comment: The event listeners are not a problem, it's just they don't have any effect.  But OK, I will try it the updated answer (when it gets updated).

Comment: I updated my answer to do just what your original ```background.js``` was doing. Hopefully, that fixes your problem now.

Comment: Run this script just like you were running your original script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229739/discussion-between-lakshya-raj-and-lnogueir).

Comment: Thanks for all of your help in the chat.  I've upvoted, accepted, and given a bounty to your answer.  Have fun with your extra 75 rep!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Feel free to open an issue on the repo if you have any other issue.